# Updating a hosted 5.3 laravel web site in BLUEHOST

Tags: laravel, caching, browser, hosting, development-environment

I'am currently working on a hosted web site which was developed with **Laravel 5.3** in **Bluehost** . So for futher developments I have folled below procedure.

1. Compressed the folder and downloaded it in to local machine.
2. Created a public folder and moved relevant folders into it.
3. Via `php artisan serve` develpment started and everything went fine.

After the development only 4 files to be changed in the server. So I have opened the related files in server and updated the coding by just copy and paste.

When I refresh the web url after updating files I can see that php
 and html updated correctly but css and javascript was not
 updated. So I checked the files again but they are almost updated. But
 when I view the source I can see that both css and javascript
 files have not updated.

So I just created new files in the server with different names and linked them into the `blade.php` files and then css and javascript working fine .Also when I view the source they are also updated.

Can anyone say what is the reason for this?

Comment: are you using Cloudflare service?

Comment: That may be the case, log into your Cloudflare account and select your domain. go the caching section and Purge Cache and give it a try.

Comment: yes, I will add it as an answer. glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to caching most of the time.
If you are using Cloudflare as a service purge the cache and give it a try.

**Steps to purge your domain cache due to Cloudflare**

STEP 01

Login to your Cloudflare account and select the domain you want to purge the cache.

STEP 02

Go to the caching tab.

STEP 03

In there, there are two options you can select. one is, you can purge the cache on selected file by simply given the URL of the file you want to purge the cache.

the second one is you can purge all cache in Cloudflare server under your domain by clicking purge everything button.